# How to fetch a URL in Play 2?

Tags: http, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

Sync? Async?

Can someone provide a code sample and/or link to the relevant documenetation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Play WS API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaWS) is probably that what are you looking for